# Why is Label Text not fully displayed

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I´m using a Label on a Dialog in my WinForms Application.
The Text is set in the Constuctor-Method of the Dialog.
After setting the Text is filled correctly. 
in this case:

```
label1.Text = @"Datum von muss ausgefüllt sein.";
```

The Designer data of the Control and the Dialog seem to be correct.

```
// 
// label1
// 
this.label1.AutoSize = true;

// 
// WincaratMessageBox
// 
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
this.AutoSize = true;
```

The when the dialog is shown. The Label-Text is not fully displayed.

In Quick Watch: label1.Text  "Datum von muss ausgefüllt sein."
and when i copy my Dialog with Ctrl + C -> Ctrl + V into notepad 
the complete text is copied as well.

[image: Displayed Dialog]

In some other cases with much longer texts the box is displayed correctly.

[image: Correct Dialog]

**EDIT 1:**
When I add some Environment.NewLines to my LabelText the Text is fully displayed. It seems like the Label AutoSizing is not working correctly.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you have some kind of control that overlaps the label? For example a panel without borders is invisible.

Comment: There is No other control on the Dialog that could overlap the label. 
There are just the buttons on the bottom.

Comment: Is there any layout controls?

Comment: The buttons are displayed dynamically on the bottom. On the left side of the label a panel is placed. i also tried to use label1.BringToFront();  -> nothing changed.

Comment: Change auto sizing to false, stretch label from left to right control side, set anchors to left and right and text alignment to middle center. What you get?

Comment: In this case the text is displayed completely. But it does not work with texts that are longer than my dialog is

Answer (score 3):

You should set the AutoSize to true not false

Answer (score 0):

Set `AutoSize` to `false` so you can change size of  label( related to text length that you want display in your label ) .change the size in designer manually

```
this.label1.AutoSize = false;
```

If you want `AutoSize` to be `true` , you must set `Label` position in where that there is enough space for displaying your message .if not , it will go under another controls

Comment: but i have different long texts i want to have them all displayed in the label so i should calculate the target size ? with number of characters, newLines and that stuff ?

Comment: No .just drag borders of label and enlarge it  until you think that the label will display the largest message

Comment: thats not possible, the dialog should look like a messagebox and sould enlarge dynamically at runtime. But it is not going under other controls in my case, its just not fully displayed ?

Comment: You can enlarge label and it is not related to it want to be message box .you can check it.also label has `UseCompatibleTextRendering` and `AutoEllipsis` change them and test it

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem, adding an `Enivroment.New Line` to the Text so the AutoSizing of the Label works and the Text wont be cut off.

Nevertheless thanks for your support.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't defined a clear position of the label. So the label gets repositioned, if the text is long enough. Maybe you should define a proper position for the label.

Comment: i have a Location defined. this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(84, 9);

Comment: Then please write it in your question.